# Is this a Chinese symbol? Cufflinks that belonged to my uncle

Tags: meaning, phrase

[image]This pair of cufflinks belonged to my uncle who worked in California. I recently was given the cufflinks and to date have not been able to figure out what they represent. I have included a picture, but I'm not sure if it is upside down or not. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, but no pictures are shown here.

Comment: Thank you! I thought I had included a picture, which I just did - hoping it helps!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn’t about the Chinese language.

Comment: It could be phrased as: "⿳ 吅口" but that doesn't give any results https://www.google.com/search?biw=1280&bih=674&ei=4e2lW-yCJ4Gn8QWsmpToAw&q=%22%E2%BF%B3%F0%A0%B1%A0+%E5%90%85%E5%8F%A3%22&oq=%22%E2%BF%B3%F0%A0%B1%A0+%E5%90%85%E5%8F%A3%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...1888.5828.0.6075.4.4.0.0.0.0.163.591.0j4.4.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.1.135...35i39k1.0.tOP27ajBxCo (or if sideways: "⿲⿳口口口⿱口口口" but that's even less likely)

Comment: @user3306356 It's a pity that they weren't stacked [like this](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/zidian/ytz_44233j.html).

Answer (score 2):

Nope, it's just five squares, which there's no character for in Chinese.

Comment: Uhm, it's 6 actually

Answer (score 1):

There is no character that I know of in Chinese but there is a similar character pin(3) 品 which means product or commodity.